# Accessing to localhost with AXIOS in Vue project

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

How could I get access to my JSON file locally with the Vue project?

I can use it with some external link (and it works):

```
mounted() {
    this.loading = true;
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((res) => {
      this.posts = res.data;
      this.loading = false;
      this.sliceIt();
});
```

But I would like to put this file (todos.json) temporarily to src/assets/todos.json and use it from there.

But this:
`axios.get("http://localhost/assets/todos.json").then((res) => {`
doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get data from custom folder with axios. You should use a static folder to save todos.json file. So you should change axios call to like this:

```
axios.get("/static/todos.json")
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! Will this work after run build?

Comment: You're welcome, probably yes.